# XmlSerializer Declaring multiple implementations with the same XmlElement ElementName

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I like to serialize with the `XmlSerializer`

```
    [XmlElement("Message", typeof(ObjectMessage))]
    [XmlElement("Message", typeof(ListMessage))]
    [XmlElement("Message", typeof(StateMessage))]
    public Message Message { get; set; }
```

Exception:

> xmlserializer The xml attribute "Message" was already specified in
>   namespace.

I can only set the `ElementName` once or set some namespace for some reason. Is there a way around?

```
[XmlElement("Message", typeof(ObjectMessage))]
[XmlElement(typeof(ListMessage))]
[XmlElement(typeof(StateMessage))]
public Message Message { get; set; }
```

Comment: Multiple instances of XmlElement Attributes are mainly used for ArrayList or Object[] arrays, please see [XmlElementAttribute Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Only one element of that name can be in the given namespace, unless it is a list or array so what are you trying to do? can you provide more info

Comment: It's a an object that get passed through the base class. Message is a baseclass of ObjectMessage, ListMessage... I solved this by simply given it a namespace.